# Xamarin UITest [IOS]: Share file from app through automation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-ui-automation, file-sharing, xamarin.uitest

I am using **Xamarin.UITest** to automate **iOS** app test. I have to **automate file sharing** from app through mail.
Do Xamarin UItest supports file sharing for iOS ? Or is there any other 3rd party library available ?

Answer (score 0):

Using UI Testing, you are not going to be able to perform actions in other apps.

If your app shares file and sends emails within itself, yes you can do that. But if it requires another app to perform the action, you can't.

You will just have to create a conditional that checks for the build configuration, and if it is a UITest, then execute different code so that your test is not locked in a state where it has no control.

Eg:App Review dialogs like this can't be UITested: [image: App Review dialog]